# Convert spark to pandas dataframe has Exception: arrow is not supported when using file-based collect

Tags: python, pandas, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to convert a spark dataframe to pandas dataframe on Azure databricks. But I get the following error:

Exception: arrow is not supported when using file-based collect

I have tried the reference code using the link: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/spark-pandas.html

First I read csv file using the following line:

```
#read file
df1 = spark.read.csv('/mnt/test/sample.csv', header = True)
```

Next I try to convert this to pandas dataframe using this code below:

```
# Enable Arrow-based columnar data transfers
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
# Convert the Spark DataFrame to a Pandas DataFrame
pandas_df = df1.select("*").toPandas()
```

But while doing this I get this error: 
Exception: arrow is not supported when using file-based collect

Here is the full expansion of the error message:

```
Exception: arrow is not supported when using file-based collect
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3700677352136413> in <module>()
      2 spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
      3 # Convert the Spark DataFrame to a Pandas DataFrame
----> 4 pandas_df = df1.select("*").toPandas()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
   2169                         _check_dataframe_localize_timestamps
   2170                     import pyarrow
-> 2171                     batches = self._collectAsArrow()
   2172                     if len(batches) > 0:
   2173                         table = pyarrow.Table.from_batches(batches)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in _collectAsArrow(self)
   2225         """
   2226         if self._sc._conf.get(self._sc._jvm.PythonSecurityUtils.USE_FILE_BASED_COLLECT()):
-> 2227             raise Exception("arrow is not supported when using file-based collect")
   2228         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
   2229             sock_info = self._jdf.collectAsArrowToPython()

Exception: arrow is not supported when using file-based collect
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution. It was the Runtime version of the cluster that had to be changed. Created a new cluster and tested with it Runtime Version 5.5 and it seemed to run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly read the csv file using `pandas` from the mount path of `dbfs`? Such as I did it as the code and figure below.

```
pdf = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/mnt/test/test.csv')
```

[image]

And I ran the code below successfully without any error on Azure Databricks.

```
pdf = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/mnt/test/test.csv')
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
pandas_df = df1.select("*").toPandas()
```

[image]